# How to remove and change the value inside of Session php?

Tags: php, session

I got 2 pages **schedule.php** and **sched_confirmation.php** in the **schedule.php** what I do there is I have a code that calculate a fee and store it in Session,

```
$calc=$result+$result1+$result2+$result3+$result4+$result5+$result6+$result7+$result8+$result9;
$num_format=number_format($calc,2);
$_SESSION['fee']= $num_format;
```

and in the **sched_confirmation** here is I want to show the value of the session

```
<form method="post">
<?php echo $_SESSION['fee'];
<button class="btn btn-warning" name="cancel">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

what I want is if I click the cancel button it would remove the value of session and redirect to **schedule.php** and create a new value for the session.

here is what I got so far

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST["cancel"])) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['fee'])) {
        unset($_SESSION['fee']);


    }else
    {
        $_SESSION['fee'];
    }
    header("Location: schedule.php");

}
?>
```

it does redirect me to the previous page but when I create new value for the session when its done and go to **sched_confirmation.php** it shows "Undefined index: fee "
How can I fix this? thank you in advance

Comment: You are already unsetting unset($_SESSION['fee']); So how will it be accessible in  sched_confirmation.php? Isn't it obvious ?

Comment: why do you use session for that purpose ? you could just pass on an hidden field the fee ; the code will be easier to understand by the way

Comment: @Vishal  It is inside the if (isset($_POST["cancel"])) { so if the button 'cancel' is clicked I thought it would unset the session thats what I understand

Comment: @JamesSerrano If i get your point right you just $_SESSION['fee'] = 'new value' remove unset staement

Comment: Just having `$_SESSION['fee'];` (as in your else block) doesn't set the session. That actually tries to _read_ from it, which obviously doesn't work (since this only happens when you've explicitly checked that it doesn't exist). That's just one of the logical issues with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question I can say you always want $_SESSION['fee'] to be available, So this is what you need

```
<?php
session_start();
if ( isset($_POST["cancel"]) ) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['fee'])) {
        $_SESSION['fee'] = 'New Value';
    }
    header("Location: schedule.php");
}
?>
```

There is no need to unset $SESSION['fee'] if you want it to be available later, Just update the value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set session value.

try this

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['cancel'])) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['fee'])) {
        unset($_SESSION['fee']);
    } else {
        $_SESSION["fee"] = "Session value";
    }
    header("Location: schedule.php");
}
?>
```